# Where to get the debug version of indesign cs5?

Tags: debug, version, adobe-cs5

I want to create plugins on my own. Before doing that, I am trying to  run the samples given in the Indesign sdk samples. I am using Mac, I  downloaded the entire eclipse archive and set the indesgn cs5 sdk in the  preference of eclipse. If i run some samples like BasicDialog, it is  running successful and plugin is created. And for other samples like  transparencyeffectui, I am getting only build is successful but no  plugin is created. I dont know why this is happening for other samples.

And the another main problem is, I copied the plugin created for  BasicDialog and pasted it inside the plugin folder of indesign. But when  i open my indesign cs5, I am getting the following message

"Adobe Indesign cannot load the BasicDialog.sdk.IndesignPlugin  plug-in. The BasicDialog.sdk.IndesignPlugin plug-in requires the debug  version of Indesign. Please contact the vendor to get a compatible  version of BasicDialog.sdk.IndesignPlugin."

I dont know where to get the debug version of indesign cs5, can  anyone tell me where it is available ?

Answer (score 1):

You should call/email whoever sold you the software, or Adobe. Adobe would definitely be able to point you in the right direction.